# Export data from sqlite database to csv

Tags: python-2.7

Iam trying build a budget app in Python and, and I have four tables, and I am trying to export this to csv file or excel for summarize later.
The code has two parts frontend and backend.

```
def summarize_of_total_expenses_command(): # Frontend
    list1.delete(0,END)
    database.summarize_of_total_expenses()
    list1.insert(END)

def summarize_of_total_expenses(self,ExpensesName,Amount,WhichAccount,Timestamp): # Backend
        self.curs = conn.cursor()
        self.curs.execute("select * from book")
        self.m_dict = list(curs.fetchall())

        with open("mycsvfile.csv", "wb") as f:
            self.w = csv.DictWriter(f, m_dict[0].keys())
            self.w.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in m_dict[0].keys()))
            self.w.writerows(m_dict)
```

If I runs the code I don't get any error message, when activated function, the csv file is updated but no content is displayed

Comment: Problem solved :-)

Comment: How to display the solution? I am new here at stackflow